# JQuery UI bounce effect - bounce only once on entering div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bounce

I have a div that I want to bounce once, when the mouse enters/hovers over the div.

The code I have works in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/73/

In Chrome it bounces once as desired but in FF and IE the bouncing goes on as long as the mouse remains in place.

I also tried `$('#box').one("mouseenter", function() {` but the box bounces once, and subsequent entries into the div do not trigger the effect.

Any thoughts on why the browsers are behaving differently and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iveval/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("#box").hover(function(){
if ( !$(this).data("bouncing") ){
      $(this).effect("bounce", { direction: 'up', distance: 10, times: 1 })
             .data("bouncing", true);
}
},function () {
     $(this).data("bouncing", false);
});
```

Once it bounces, the element data attribute will hold the `true` boolean, 
inside the `if` statement we just check for it's `true` or `false`.

On mouse-leave we just set it to false, to allow a new hover and a... new bounce! :)

**You can also write the above like:**

```
$("#box").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ) {
  var el = $(this);
  if(!el.data("b"))el.effect("bounce", {direction:'up',distance:10,times:1} );
  el.data("b",e.type=="mouseenter"?true:false);
});
```